# How to make vscode call snippet from shortcut keybindings instead of asking user to 'select a snippet'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, key-bindings, vscode-snippets, vscode-keybinding

An hour ago, my snippets and keybindings were working in VSCode. I must have changed a setting on accident?

Problem:
When I use custom keyboard shortcuts to call custom snippets, the snippet does not run. Instead, vscode provides a dropdown menu with all of my snippets (those with and without keybindings) and asks me to select one. But I shouldn't have to select one - the keybinding already 'knows' which snippet it should have ran.

How can I make my snippet run again with the keyboard shortcut?

```
{
  "example snippet": {
    "prefix": "ex",
    "body": "const example = `${1:exampleText}`",
    "description": "Example: exampleText"
  }
}
```

When I type `ex` + `tab` in my editor - it works.

Here is my keybinding

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+e ctrl+x",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "arg": {
      "name": "example snippet"
    }
  }
```

But when I press `ctrl e x`, a dropdown appears asking to select my snippet.

[image]

How do I fix this behavior? It only asks me to select a snippet if the keyboard shortcut points to a snippet. For example, when I press Ctrl+C, this drop-down does not appear. It knows it is a snippet, but it thinks it doesn't know which snippet!

Comment: It is `args`, not `arg` - which are you using in your keybinding?

Comment: Yes, I must have accidentally changed the args to arg without noticing. Thanks.